# Erlang inference

Tags: erlang, inference

The following source doesn't compile because `Stopover` is unbound.

I'm new to Erlang, how can I rewrite it?

```
-module(distances).
-export([ path/2 ]).

path( madrid, paris ) ->
   { km, 1049 };
path( paris, moscou ) ->
   { km, 2482 };
path( moscou, berlin ) ->
   { km, 1603 };
path( From, To ) ->
   path( From, Stopover ) + path( Stopover, To ).
```

The usage of this module maybe:

```erlang
path( madrid, moscou ).
```

And the epected answer should be `{ km, 3531}`.

Comment: What would be your algorithm to figure out the right value for `Stopover`? You need to implement it, probably in another function, like `Stopover = find_stopover(From, To)`

Comment: From the looks of it you're trying to use Erlang as Prolog. Erlang does not have an engine to derive knowledge, which is what @BrujoBenavides is referring to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The following source doesn't compile because Stopover is unbound.
>
> I'm new to Erlang, how can I rewrite it?

Look at this code:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

do_stuff() ->
    Stopover.
```

Here's what happens when I try to compile it:

> a.erl:5: variable 'Stopover' is unbound

The variable `Stopover` was never assigned a value, so erlang has no idea what should be returned by the function `do_stuff()`.  You are doing something similar here:

```
path( From, Stopover ) + path( Stopover, To ).
```

The variables `From` and `To` are parameter variables for the function `path()`, and when `path()` is called, e.g. `path(madrid, moscow)`, then `madrid` will be assigned to the variable `From`, and `moscow` will be assigned to the variable `To`.   Note, however, that nowhere do you assign any value to the variable `Stopover`.

You need to redefine `path()` to look like this:

```
path(From, To, Stopover) ->
```

Next, you should try to see if adding tuples actually works:

```
2> {km, 5} + {km, 3}.
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in operator  +/2
        called as {km,5} + {km,3}
3>
```

Nope!

What you need to do is use pattern matching to extract the distance, an integer, from each tuple, then add the two integers:

```
{km, Distance1} = path( From, Stopover ),
...             = path(Stopover, To),

{km, Distance1 + Distance2}.
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered by @7stud, and I was wondering how to implement such a path search in erlang. Here is a possible solution:

```
-module(distances).
-export([ path/2,getTowns/0,start/1, stop/0 ]).

path(From,To) ->
    Paths = getPath(),
    path(From,To,maps:get(orderedTuple(From,To), Paths, not_found),Paths).

% distanceServer in charge to keep the liste of known distances
% server interfaces
start(Towns) ->
    {ok,List} = file:consult(Towns),
    Paths = lists:foldl(fun({A,B,D},Acc) -> maps:put(orderedTuple(A,B), D, Acc) end,#{},List),
    start(Paths,distance_server).

stop() ->
 distance_server ! stop.

getTowns() ->
    K = maps:keys(getPath()),
    L = lists:usort(lists:flatten([[A,B] || {A,B} <- K])),
    io:format("list of towns :~n~p~n~n",[L]).

getPath() ->
 distance_server ! {getPath,self()},
 receive
    Path -> Path
 end.

% server fuctions
start(Paths,Server) ->
    Pid = spawn(fun() -> distanceServer(Paths) end),
    register(Server, Pid).

distanceServer(Path) ->
    receive 
        stop -> stop;
        {getPath,From} ->
            From ! Path,
            distanceServer(Path)
        end.

% Searching path
path(From,To,not_found,Paths) -> % if not in the known list, seach for the shortest path
    {KM,P} = searchBestPath({0,[From]},To,maps:keys(Paths),{no_dist,no_path}),
    case P of 
        no_path -> not_found;
        _ -> {lists:reverse(P),KM}
    end;
path(From,To,KM,_) ->  % else give the result. Assumption: the known path contains always the best one.
    {[From,To],KM}.

searchBestPath({N,[To|_]}=Path,To,_,{BestD,_}) when N < BestD -> Path; % keep the new path if it is better
searchBestPath({N,_},_,_,{BestD,_}=Best) when N >= BestD -> Best; % cancel search if the path so far is longer or equal to the best found
searchBestPath({D,[H|_]=PathSoFar},To,Remaining,Best) ->
    Next = [remove(H,{A,B}) || {A,B} <- Remaining, (A =:= H) orelse (B =:= H)], % list of all possible next steps
    case Next of 
        [] -> Best;
        Next  -> lists:foldl(
                    fun(X,Acc) ->
                        {_,ND} = path(H,X), % will always match
                        R = Remaining -- [orderedTuple(H,X)], % necessary to avoid possible infinite loop in the first search
                        searchBestPath({D+ND,[X|PathSoFar]},To,R,Acc) % evaluate path for all possible next steps
                    end,
                    Best,Next)
    end.

% helpers
orderedTuple(A,B) when B > A -> {A,B};
orderedTuple(A,B) -> {B,A}.

remove(X,{X,B}) -> B;
remove(X,{A,X}) -> A.
```

it uses an external file to define the "known distances", I have used this one for test:

```
{paris,lyon,465}.
{lyon,marseille,314}.
{marseille,nice,198}.
{marseille,toulouse,404}.
{toulouse,bordeaux,244}.
{bordeaux,paris,568}.
{bordeaux,nantes,347}.
{nantes,paris,385}.
{paris,lille,225}.
{paris,strasbourg,491}.
{lille,strasbourg,525}.
{lille,bruxelles,120}.
{rennes,brest,244}.
{rennes,paris,351}.
{rennes,nantes,113}.
```

and the result in the shell:

```
1> c(distances).                    
{ok,distances}
2> distances:start("distances.txt").
true
3> distances:getTowns(). 
list of towns :
[bordeaux,brest,bruxelles,lille,lyon,marseille,nantes,nice,paris,rennes,
 strasbourg,toulouse]

ok
4> distances:path(bordeaux,bruxelles).
{[bordeaux,paris,lille,bruxelles],913}
5> distances:path(nice,bruxelles).    
{[nice,marseille,lyon,paris,lille,bruxelles],1322}
6> distances:path(moscou,paris).
not_found
7> distances:stop().            
stop
8>
```

next step could be to increase the list of known distances each time a new request is done.